# Crashlytics log function is crashing in CLSUserLogging.m

Tags: crashlytics, google-fabric

Fabric Crashlytics is crashing on calling CLSLogv method occasionally. The crash is very random, not sure on what input it's crashing.

Here is the crash log:

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  CoreFoundation                 0x18289d688 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 12780
1  CoreFoundation                 0x18289a464 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 244
2  Foundation                     0x1831b6320 -[NSPlaceholderString initWithFormat:locale:arguments:] + 168
3  Dream11                        0x1004823e4 CLSLogv (CLSUserLogging.m:368)
4  Dream11                        0x1001d73a8 specialized crashlyticsLog(format : String, [CVarArg], file : String, function : String, line : Int) -> () (LogManager.swift)`
```

Here is the method.

```
func VERBOSELOG(_ format: String = "",
            _ args:[CVarArg] = [],
            file: String = #file,
            function: String = #function,
            line: Int = #line) {
    if ENABLED_LOGGING.contains("VERBOSE") {
        do {
           try crashlyticsLog(format: "\nVERBOSE: " + format, args, file: file, function: function, line: line)
        } catch let error {
           print(error)
        }
    }
}

func crashlyticsLog(format: String = "",
                _ args:[CVarArg] = [],
                file: String = #file,
                function: String = #function,
                line: Int = #line) throws {
     let filename = file.components(separatedBy: "/").last!.components(separatedBy: ".").first!
     #if SWIFT_DEBUG
         print("\(filename).\(function) line \(line) $ \(format)")
     #else
         CLSLogv("\(filename).\(function) line \(line) $ \(format)", getVaList(args))
     #endif
}
```

Comment: Please add the actual relevant code that's causing the crash.

Comment: @GustavoStraube I have updated the description

Comment: Mike from Fabric here, that should only crash when something that was added would also crash NSLog. One thing to check is which type of data you're trying to log there and ensure that it's safe.

Comment: @MikeBonnell since this is Swift, if the value of format is not String or nil it should have crashed when I called crashlyticsLog method. Instead its crashing after calling CLSLogv

Comment: Yea, that makes sense on it being Swift, but it is tough to reproduce what you're seeing based on the limited information. I did some testing and couldn't reproduce any crashes in this area unfortunately.

Comment: @MikeBonnell how can I add try catch statement to CLSLogv, so that even if the method crashes, the app is doesn't crash. I have updated the question description with updated code

Comment: If CLSLogv is crashing, then anything being logged even it wasn't with CLSLogv would also crash.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue here. The code is pretty simple:

if deals.count > 0 {
...
DLog("loaded deals \(deals.count)")
}

func DLog(_ message: Any, file: StaticString = #file, function: StaticString = #function, line: Int = #line) {
    let filename = NSURL(string:String.init(describing:file))?.lastPathComponent?.components(separatedBy:".").first ?? "<Unknown>"
    
    
    #if DEBUG
        print("[\(filename):\(line)] \(function) - \(message)")
    #else
        CLSLogv("[\(filename):\(line)] \(function) - \(message)", getVaList([""]))
    #endif
}

Comment: #0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1d0c5634 strlen + 28
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1d977fe7 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 9574
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1d977fe7 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 9574
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1d975a67 _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 188
6  Restolastminute                0xdd509 CLSLogv (CLSUserLogging.m:333)
7  Restolastminute                0x5ca88 DLog(Any, file : StaticString, function : StaticString, line : Int) -> () (Logger.swift:19)

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar crash, that happened randomly with following stack trace

```
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1b99b84d4 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 6000
1  CoreFoundation                 0x1b99ba5bc _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 136
2  flockmail                      0x1006725ec CLSLogv + 374 (CLSUserLogging.m:374)
```

The problem that I later figured out was the way I was logging messages.

```
CLSLogv(message, getVaList([])) // Incorrect
```

I was passing message in the format, so if the message had some `%@`'s or `%d`'s or `%0` or similar stuff, then it would look for vaList to replace it.

Fix was

```
CLSLogv("%@", getVaList([message]))
```

In you case, it seems format is supplied from outside, just make sure the `format` string parameter is in sync with `args` parameter.

Further references : 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html
https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html#custom-logs

Answer (score 0):

Is it the character limit of NSLog, I had the same crash for `NSLog` and `CLSLogv`. Not for `print`